# overflow-y doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -28px;
}
#push {
  height: 28px;
}
header {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
}
footer {
  background-color: black;
  height: 28px;
}
main {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <header>
  </header>

  <main>
    <table width="3000" height="2000" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>sd</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </main>

  <div id="push"></div>

</div>

<footer>
</footer>
```

---

As a result `div.wrapper` stretches along y axis, but footer stays at the same place. Overflow-x works properly. How do I enable normal y-scrolling? And why is the footer fixed?

Problem with footer is solved by adding `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` string.

Comment: Try giving main a `height` or `max-height`. Also `height: 100%;` doesn't work unless you give your html and body 100% height. Try adding this to the top of your css `html, body{ height: 100%; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Calculate the height of your `wrapper` div as `100vh` minus `28px` (which is the height of your `footer`.
2. Remove `margin` from your `wrapper`. It is not required.
3. Set `overflow:hidden` on your `wrapper`.
4. Calculate height of your `main` as `100%` minus `28px` (of `push`) minus `100px` (of `header`)
5. Set appropriate `overflow:auto` on `main`.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding:0; margin: 0; }
#wrapper {
  height: calc(100vh - 28px);
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#push { height: 28px; background-color: yellow; }
header { background-color: green; height: 100px; }
footer { background-color: black; height: 28px; }
main {
  height: calc(100% - 100px - 28px);
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <table width="3000" height="2000" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>sd</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </main>
  <div id="push"></div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

*<sub>Note: Edited the answer back to reflect `main`. As pointed out by @Oriol, `main` is very much a valid HTML5 element.</sub>*

Comment: Just be careful. Calc doesn't work on some older browsers (IE 8 and below for example).

Comment: The method does not work with dynamic content of `.main`. Can I change it?

Comment: @Leonidas: What do you mean by dynamic content of `.main`. You can have anything inside your `.main` and it should work.

Comment: I place a large table inside this div using Django templates. When I do it `.main` stretches vertically and `.wrapper` hides this overflow.

Comment: @Leonidas: It's very difficult to say anything based on the description. Can you create a fiddle based on the above code and then dump the HTML generated by your templates. That way it would be helpful to see what's going on.

Comment: "*`main` is not an element*". It is in HTML5. See [The `main` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-main-element).

Comment: @Oriol: thank you so much. never realised that! so much to read, so much to learn, everyday.